# How to write expression in custom search parameter for retrieving claim resource based on diagnosis code?

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, azure-health-data-services

I am using Azure Health Data Services - FHIR service

In FHIR Claim resource, we have diagnosis property. Inside the diagnosis property --> diagnosisCodeableConcept --> code.

Now I want to create a custom search parameter to retrieve claim resources based on Code value inside diagnosis property.

What should be the value in expression property of custom search parameter?

**Can you please provide the Custom search parameter for the above?**

I gave the following expression value: Claim.diagnosisCodeableConcept.code. But I am getting 424 Failed dependency. What is the reason for this?

Comment: `Claim.diagnosisCodeableConcept.code` doesn't exist in FHIR. CodeableConcepts consist of `coding` and `text`, and within `coding` is where `code` lives. Have you tried `Claim.diagnosisCodeableConcept.coding.code`?

Comment: I tried Claim.diagnosisCodeableConcept.coding.code now. I am getting 424 failed dependency as the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the R4 specification for [Claim](https://hl7.org/fhir/claim-definitions.html#Claim.diagnosis.diagnosis_x_) you'll note that the correct path to the diagnosis is:

```
Claim.diagnosis.trace('d').diagnosis
```

:test_tube: [Test with FHIRPath-Lab](https://fhirpath-lab.com/FhirPath?parameters=N4IgpgHgDgTmDO8CWB7AdiAXCAwgGwEMkBbAOgBMkCBzNFZeUgFxgIGMwAKAcnO4EoKVWvSTwQAGhBt0TSEyzg0LAJ6k48FAFcYHSSA3bdYRfiLEA-AH0ZW5QF4AjAAZ9YNNSRoT2AGYALJBgoAiZ-UgArcSk5GGIvFDwUahUAZTAYADcMxX8mJih4TAB6YvgARyS0AKCAWhgAFlICAC8dMAB3MAAjZDlGbyZimph9TIIYKm68BCwAbQBdAF8gA)

I hope you've defined the search parameter as a `token` type, which creates indexes on CodeableConcept types.
You likely don't need to cast down to the type as the search engine will handle that anyway.

You don't also drill into the `coding.code` as the search indexer knows how to process the type, and it also permits the usage of the codesystem prefix on the search too

e.g.

```
Claim?diagnosis=http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/icd-10|G89.4
```

**Edit:** Try this search parameter

```json
{
    "resourceType": "SearchParameter",
    "id": "claim-diagnosis",
    "url": "http://example.org/SearchParameter/claim-diagnosis",
    "version": "0.1",
    "name": "ClaimDiagnosis",
    "status": "active",
    "date": "2023-09-10",
    "publisher": "Brian Postlethwaite",
    "description": "Claim diagnosis",
    "code": "diagnosis",
    "base": [
        "Claim"
    ],
    "type": "token",
    "expression": "diagnosis.diagnosis.ofType(CodeableConcept)",
    "xpathUsage": "normal",
    "multipleOr": true,
    "multipleAnd": true
}
```

Comment: HI @Brian Postlethwaite I gave the same expression that you mentioned with type: token. The response is 424 Failed Dependency (The method or operation is not implemented)

Comment: Revised the comment with what I tested with

Answer (score 1):

Your expression would need to be:
`Claim.diagnosis.diagnosis as CodeableConcept`
The type of your search parameter should be 'token'.
The token type will automatically find a match if any of the codings match your specified search string (based on code and/or system, depending on what the user specified)

Comment: I tried giving Claim.diagnosis as CodeableConcept expression. 
**POST {{fhirUrl}}/SearchParamter** was successfull.

However, when I made the following request:
**GET {{fhirUrl}}/Claim/{{claimId}}/$reindex**  which is to list down the supported search parameters, I am not able to view the submitted custom search parameter.

Comment: Also, @Lloyd McKenzie Can you please tell how to learn writing these expressions for custom search parameters in general?

Comment: The support for new custom search parameters varies from server to server.  I've poked someone on the Azure side to respond.  The rules for writing FHIRPath (which is what's used inside SearchParameter) are [here](http://hl7.org/fhirpath/) with some FHIR-specific supplements [here](http://build.fhir.org/fhirpath)

Comment: I've updated my post above to include the resource that I tested with.
Note the difference in the expressions `as` and `.ofType()` ofType will work if there are multiple diagnosis, were the as will throw an exception (and not be indexed)